# NodeRed not loading up when adding modules to the flow

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, node-modules, node-red

I'm working on a project using NodeRed deployed with docker, I am using nginx location block to navigate to the particular container like http://localhost/project/projectId/port/? when I trigger this url first time it is showing up the node red flow but when I add modules from the Manage pallet and hit the same url http://localhost/project/projectId/port/? is not opening the flow and it is getting stuck at loading, what is the thing happening when adding modules to not adding modules and how to resolve this issue is any thing we can do it from nginx location block?

Before adding modules

[image]

After adding modules

[image: Nodered is getting stuck]

Nginx configuration

```
   location ~ "/project/projectid/([0-9]+)/(.*)" {
            set $port $3;
            set $token $4;
            rewrite ^/project/projectid/[0-9]+(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port/$token;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods *;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

The one i see in the console is

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

http://localhost/project/projectId/port/nodes/messages?lng=en-GB&_=1670325432158 1

Loading Node catalogs screen stuck there

Comment: Edit the question to show the nginx configuration and any errors shown in the browser's developer tools.  (but you can not have multiple instances on the same host, proxied by path)

Comment: Yes i have updated those

Comment: You need to look in the browser console logs as well, but I'll stop you now, this just will not work, the Node-RED authentication will not allow you to log into multiple instances on the same hostname. You have to use a different hostname for each instance.

Comment: Yes i am using different port right without changing the host name.

Comment: No you are not, you are proxying them all through 1 hostname and port. As far as the browser is concerned it's all the same single host.

Comment: So what need to be done how to use different hostname, is anything need to be done from nginx side

Comment: I'm saying you will need to access project X at `x.somedomain.com` and project Y at `y.somedomain.com` This will require setting up a wildcard DNS entry. But you should try and debug the 400 error first.

Comment: yes not able to find the solution to the issue yet

Comment: It is working fine without nginx location block but with nginx proxy pass it is not giving up the result

Comment: Use something link wireshark to see what is actually being forwarded to the Node-RED instance

Comment: The one thing i found in the browser network is issue with 

{code: "unexpected_error", message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"}
code
: 
"unexpected_error"
message
: 
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"